# Is it possible to remove the extension part of SSL handshakes in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, https, handshake, jsse

There is a legacy Cisco IPS server which I am trying to connect to using https. The problem is this server only accepts handshakes with certain conditions:

The version must be TLSv1.0, the cipher suite must be SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 or SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA and there mustn't be any extensions.

I implemented a hand-made "ClientHello" which sends the following info as handshake (wireshark output):

```
Secure Sockets Layer
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 45
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 41
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Random
        Session ID Length: 0
        Cipher Suites Length: 2
        Cipher Suites (1 suite)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
```

The server sends back the ServerHello message.

Now I want to use Java's SSL implementation to send **exactly** the same ClientHello. The following code:

```
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake");

    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("ips-server", 443);

    socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1"});
    socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {"SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5"});

    socket.startHandshake();
```

produces the following handshake:

```
Secure Sockets Layer
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 52
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 48
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Random
        Session ID Length: 0
        Cipher Suites Length: 2
        Cipher Suites (1 suite)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
        Extensions Length: 5
        Extension: renegotiation_info
            Type: renegotiation_info (0xff01)
            Length: 1
            Renegotiation Info extension
```

This causes the server to send back the following packet:

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)
```

Is it possible to make Java **not** send the "extension" part of the packet?

Comment: Setting `https.protocols` has no effect unless you're using `HttpsURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wants to know the answer, you need to use SSLv2Hello for https.protocols System property.

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,SSLv2Hello");
```

I used the following code to connect to the server:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null; 
    }
} }, new SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);

HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

**EDIT** More explanation - 
@EJP mentioned that this code does not answer the question in the title. I wrote a small test to show if the extension part of SSL client hello is removed as a side effect of changing the client hello to SSLv2.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,SSLv2Hello");

    String url = "https://www.google.com";

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }}, new SecureRandom());

    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    Stream<String> lines = br.lines();
    lines.forEach(l -> { System.out.println(l);});
}
```

This is what I get in wireshark if I run this program: 
[image]

And if I comment out the SSLv2Client part, I'd get this: 
[image]

So clearly this achieves what I was looking for: Removing the extension part of the SSL handshake. Maybe this is not the best way and as @EJP mentioned introduces a lot of security holes (not my concern here, as my CISCO IPS server is local and I just wanted to connect to it, secure or not), but I couldn't find any other way to do this.

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about SSLV2ClientHello or HTTPS. There's a way to accomplish exactly this for SSLSockets, but this isn't it. According to the test in your question, SSLV2ClientHello is not necessary. There's nothing here that accomplishes what it says in your title either. All you've really done is set the TLS version and cipher suite, and introduced several glaring security holes.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for reading and commenting. I tried to give more explanation in my edit.